# How to set a routing to a website with a specific ISP?

Tags: routing, sonicwall

We use a Dell SonicWall 2600
Firmware Version: SonicOS Enhanced 6.1.2.0-11n
Safemode Version: SafeMode 6.1.0.9
ROM Version: SonicROM 5.4.0.15.

We have 2 ISPs, one fiber connection and one ADSL connection, with the Fiber connection being the most used. The ADSL connection is mostly used as a backup.

Some of our users use "a little" too much Youtube but we are not allowed by our top management to block this website so, we would like to set a rule in our firewall to route all traffic to and from youtube on the ADSL connection for all users.

I'm not really used to this firewall, can you please give me some advise? Don't mind explain with a lot of details, I know I'm a little a n00b with this device.

If you need more information, I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle sites in sonicwalls. Its somewhere like

```
Application Firewall -> Application Objects -> Add new Object
```

From there you can say I want to limit youtube to only a set % of the total bandwidth.

Check out the following for more info

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1949-sonicwall-application-firewall-setting-bandwidth-limit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will have to search a little more to apply it, I'm lost because of the difference SonicOS 5.5.1 showed in the link and the Sonic OS 6.1 of my SonicWall.